# Hawtio console login credentials

Tags: hawtio

Which are the credentials of the Hawtio web console? I have deployed Hawtio via Karaf feature and I thought that admin/admin were the credentials but not: Incorrect username or password.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Credentials are karaf/karaf as I am using the 'karaf' realm by default that comes with Apache Karaf default installation.